# Bind data from component to Html

Tags: angular

> Getting error while passing the value {id,data} from component to HTML table
> This is my Component.ts where i am getting the data from Firebase in console but unable to bind with HTML page

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/product.service';
       
@Component({
    selector: 'app-admin-products',
  templateUrl: './admin-products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-products.component.css']
})

export class AdminProductsComponent implements OnInit {
    
    table$ ;
    dataname$ ;
    data$ ;

    constructor(private productService 
        :ProductService) {  
      this.table$ = this.productService.getAll()
                .map(actions =  > {
            return actions.map(a =  > {
                const
                data = a.payload.val;
                const
                id = a.payload.key;
                console.log(id)
                return
                {id,  data
                };
            });
        });
    }
    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

> This is my HTML Page where i want to pass the data from component

```html
<p>
<a routerLink="/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary">New Product</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Country Name</th>
            <th>Currency Name</th>
            <th>Alphabetic Code</th>
            <th>Numeric Code</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let tab of table$ | async">
            <td>{{tab.countryname}}</td>
            <td>{{tab.currencyname}}</td>
            <td>{{tab.alphacode}}</td>
            <td>{{tab.numericcode}}</td>
            <td>{{tab.statuscode}}</td>

            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products', tab.id]">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

> This is my Service.component where i am getting the value from firebase

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from '@angular/fire/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs-compat/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {

    constructor(private db :AngularFireDatabase) { }
    
    getAll() {
        return this.db.list('/table'
        ).snapshotChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: In ts file your data was stored under table observable but in html you are using data observable. Please check

Comment: its still not working. i am only getting "id" from firebase not data. any other way to get data and id from firebase..?

Comment: Can you paste your response which you received under the firebase

Answer (score 0):

You return an object with id and data as property. In the html you should use tab.data.variable.